# Assigning Created Joomla User to the Current User

Tags: php, joomla

I've created a Joomla plugin for facebook which lets facebook users to login.
Also, I'm creating new user when they first login through faceobok.

I want to set the current user object to the created user. 
is it possibile in Joomla? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the current user:

```
$user = & JFactory::getUser();
$user = $newUser;
```